# AngularJS: where does the attribute 'when-scrolled' come from?

Tags: angularjs

It is the question I have when I am reading the sample code in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/

**Html**

```
<div id="fixed" when-scrolled="loadMore()">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.id}}</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

**AngularJS controller**

```
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];

    var counter = 0;
    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $scope.items.push({id: counter});
            counter += 10;
        }
    };

    $scope.loadMore();
}

angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];

        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
            }
        });
    };

});
```

I suppose `when-scrolled` is inferred from the directive name `whenScrolled` somehow. But I cannot find the a definite answer from the AngularJS documentation or googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when-scrolled` is the `whenScrolled` directive(You can see the naming convention here).

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

Read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 1):

Cases (camel Case) means dash in angular directives so whenScrolled needs to be used as when-scrolled in the html.